# Symfony2 monolog configuration: exclude warning messages from debug messages

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

I use Symfony 2.4 with monolog and have monolog configuration:

```
monolog:
    channels:               ["voter", "worker"]

    handlers:
        # 'critical' means HTTP 5XX responses.
        critical:
            type:           fingers_crossed
            action_level:   critical
            handler:        critical_group
        # 'error' means HTTP 4XX responses.
        error:
            type:           fingers_crossed
            action_level:   error
            handler:        error_stream
        debug:
            type:           fingers_crossed
            action_level:   debug
            handler:        debug_stream

        critical_group:
            type:           group
            members:        critical_stream

        critical_stream:
            type:           stream
            path:           %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_critical.log
            level:          critical
        error_stream:
            type:           stream
            path:           %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_error.log
            level:          error
        debug_stream:
            type:           stream
            path:           %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_warning.log
            level:          debug
```

I want to exclude warning messages from debug messages. And warning and debug messages from error messages for cleaner logs. Is any solution for this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`filter`](https://github.com/symfony/MonologBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L93-L98) handler.

Here an additional handler based on your config:

```
handlers:
    cleaned_debug:
        type: filter
        handler: debug
        accepted_levels: [DEBUG]
```

Comment: Could you provide example?